# Magento 2: setOrder by entity_id not working

Tags: magento2

I am trying to use that:

```
$this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'desc') or $this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'asc')
```

I always get same result as 'asc'.....

but if I use:

```
$this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'desc') or $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'asc')...
```

this is working as it should.

**Where can be a problem?**

Using Magento 2.4.2

Comment: Try this $this->_collection->getSelect->order('entity_id', 'desc');

Comment: The same problem, I tried also with your suggestion. I do not get it. If I use for example stupid idea like to replace entity_id with whatever which do not exist, then I get error... its working on "name", "price".... but not on entity_id..... so what I want is to have sort order in category view ordered by entity_id

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code. it works for me.

```
protected $shipmentCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\CollectionFactory $shipmentCollection,
) {
    $this->shipmentCollection = $shipmentCollection;
}

public function getOrderShippingDetails($order)
{
    $orderId = $order->getEntityId();
    $shipments = $this->shipmentCollection->create()
                 ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderId)
                 ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');
}
```

Comment: No no... I want to have sort order in category view

Answer (score 0):

For Product Listing pages - the Elasticsearch is used, and the "entity_id" is a filed which is not used for sorting (I am not sure why did Magento do so).
Try override the following class and set `$this->skippedFields` as empty array - `\Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Sort`